# pyODBC error - SQL_Autocommit_off is not implemented

Tags: python, odbc

I tried to use the pyODBC library to connect to a ODBC data source, but always got this error:

pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', "[HYC00] The 'SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF' for the 'SQL_ATTR_AUTO
COMMIT' is not implemented. (0) (SQLSetConnnectAttr(SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT))")

when use pyodbc.connect("DNS=...")

I also tried the pypyodbc library and got the same error. Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: Which RDMS are you trying to connect to? Please post full connection string.

Answer (score 3):

You should specify autocommit option:

```
pyodbc.connect("DNS=...", autocommit=True)
```

Comment: Worked for me when connecting to MongoDB using it's ODBC driver.