# "'SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF' … is not implemented" error with SQLAlchemy engine

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, osisoft

I have been connecting to a database using pyodbc:

```
DNS = 'PIODBC'
pi_connection = pyodbc.connect("DSN=" + DSN + ";UID=" + uid + ";PWD=" +pw, autocommit = True)
pd.read_sql_query(qry, pi_connection)
```

This uses a PI ODBC Driver apparently, which could well be a proprietary thing which lets me connect to and OSIsoft PI database. This has been working fine for me.

Recently I started getting the error message:

```
UserWarning: pandas only supports SQLAlchemy connectable (engine/connection) or database string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connection. Other DBAPI2 objects are not tested. Please consider using SQLAlchemy.
```

I still get what I want but I want to do things properly so I've considered using SQLAlchemy. I don't want to just suppress the error. The code I've used is:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine_str = "mssql+pyodbc://"+uid+":"+pw+"@"+DSN
engine = create_engine(engine_str)

with engine.connect() as con:
    rs = con.execute(qry)
```

Unfortunately that throws up an actual error:

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HYC00', "[HYC00] The 'SQL_AUTOCOMMIT_OFF' for the 'SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT' is not implemented. (0) (SQLSetConnectAttr(SQL_ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT))")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

There are a number of related questions that I have seen: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664537/python-connection-to-hive), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55126886/sqlalchemy-create-engine-and-pyodbc-dsn-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26717790/how-to-set-autocommit-1-in-a-sqlalchemy-engine-connection), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38174811/pyodbc-error-sql-autocommit-off-is-not-implemented), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082494/getting-a-warning-when-using-a-pyodbc-connection-object-with-pandas) but I am not getting it. I feel like I've tried a million variations of my code in line with what is being said in the answers to these questions but I haven't managed to move on from both the errors. I'm just not understanding it all I suppose.

I'm using Windows 10 (64 bit) and pyodbc 4.0.31 and SQLAlchemy 1.4.44

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include: (1) the client OS you are running, (2) the Driver= specified in your DSN, (3) the versions of pyodbc and SQLAlchemy you are using.

Comment: and what ODBC driver is your DSN using?

Comment: Try using `mssql+pyodbc://username:password@dsn_name?autocommit=True`

Comment: @GordThompson I tried `mssql+pyodbc://username:password@dsn_name?autocommit=True` and got a different error, so progress I suppose. I now get `DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY000', "[HY000] [PIOLEDB] Function name 'schema_name' is invalid. (DB_E_ERRORSINCOMMAND) (80040e14) (0) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: SELECT schema_name()]`

Answer (score 1):

The OSIsoft ODBC driver for PI differs sufficiently from the MS SQL Server implementations that using `mssql+pyodbc://…` with SQLAlchemy is not going to work. For now you can continue using a plain DBAPI (pyodbc) connection for `.read_sql_query()` and just ignore the warnings from pandas.

For full support with pandas — e.g., for `.to_sql()` — you will need to find (or create) a proper third-party SQLAlchemy dialect for OSIsoft PI. The technical support group at OSIsoft may be able to help you with that.